# Stress of presbyterum, presbytero

Tags: pronunciation, stress

Salvete,

Where is the stress in the various forms of *presbyter*?
Would I be correct with the following? (I have placed the apostrophe before the stressed syllable.)

Gratias vobis ago
Paulus

> nom. 'presbyter
> gen. pres'byteri
> acc. pres'byterum
> abl. pres'bytero

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to check is vowel lengths.
L&S indicates that all vowels in *presbyter* and *presbyteri* are short apart from the genitive ending *-i*.

In *presbyter* the second last syllable *by* is light (also known as short) as it is open and has a short vowel.
Therefore the stress falls on the third last syllable.
In the other forms the second last syllable is *te*, and it is light for the same reason.
Therefore the stress falls again on the third last syllable, but it is now a different syllable as the endings add a syllable.

Your stresses are thus entirely correct.

Comment: This definitely is confirmed by what I've heard. Now I'm curious, though: does Latin always follow its stress rules even for imported Greek words? I wonder what happens when the accent on the Greek word doesn't fall on the same place as Latin stress rules place it.

Comment: @brianpck My impression was always that Latin completely ignores Greek accents, which is all the more likely if the stress is realised differently in the two languages. But I've never seen this explicitly discussed, and I answered completely within Latin.